# Python-Requests skips a division on a website

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to extact the HTML of a website for a personal project, but Python-Requests seems to be skipping a division.

The website I'm working on is: https://warframe.fandom.com/wiki/Void_Relic

[Here's the HTML directly on the website:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3986.png)

[Picture of the entire browser window:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWNa9.png)

[The .txt file Python Scraped:](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ut1KyGzADUX8okajL5ufyDRFpp78D63V/view?usp=drivesdk)

Edit 1: Python version:
Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 21:26:53) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32

Edit 2:
As you can see between the screenshot above and html code below, one of the inner divisions of "

In the screenshot it goes:
div id=flytabs_0
div id_flytabs_0-content-wrapper
script

But in the code that Python scraped the second division is missing.

I formatted the HTML below myself for ease of reading. Didn't use automatic means of doing so to reduce the number of variables in the problem.

What I tried: Mostly trial and error, and Gooling to no avail.

Python code:

```py
import requests

f = open("ScrapedSite.txt", "wb")
source = requests.get("https://warframe.fandom.com/wiki/Void_Relic")

f.write(source.text.encode("utf8"))
f.close()
```

HTML output in the  of the same section of the HTML as seen in the screenshot:

```html
<div id="mw-customcollapsible-rewarddrops" class="mw-collapsible mw- 
collapsed" style="display:flow-root;">

    <div id="flytabs_0">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="/wiki/Void_Relic/ByRelic">
                    <span>By relic</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/wiki/Void_Relic/ByRarity">
                    <span>By rarity</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/wiki/Void_Relic/ByRewards">
                    <span>By rewards</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/wiki/Void_Relic/ByRewards/SimpleTable">
                    <span>By rewards (simple table)</span>
                </a>
            </li>
         </ul>
    </div>

    <script>JSSnippetsStack.push({dependencies:    
    ["/extensions/wikia/TabView/js/TabView.js","/resources/wikia/libraries 
    /mustache/mustache.js"],callback:function(json) 
    {TabView.init(json)},id:"TabView.init",options: 
    {"id":"flytabs_0","selected":0}})
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: check `source.status_code`. It's HTTP response code.

Comment: @NizamMohamed
I added `print (source.status_code)` and the output is: 200.

Comment: What do you mean by "seems to be skipping a division"? a `div` element gone?

Comment: @NizamMohamed
Short - Yes

Long: 
As you can see in the screenshot there is a division:
`<div id='mw-custom...`
And inside of it are three things:
 div, div and script

The problem is that, when I request the page with python and save the content to a txt file, or just print them to the console, the second inner div is missing (as seen in the html code.

Comment: The second `div` you mentioned should have been created by javascript code running in the browser. Python `requests` can't interpret javascript. You should fetch such javascript powered sites with [headless browsers](https://github.com/dhamaniasad/HeadlessBrowsers)

Comment: What are you trying to extract from that site? Quite often the information is contained in a separate request made by the browser.